# How to build jar and push to another github repository using jenkins scripted pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

Let's say I have two Github repository app.git and another is app_release.git.I want to pull the code from app.git build it and generate a jar and then push the jar to app_release.git.

I have created a scripted Jenkins pipeline used to pull code from a repository of GitHub, build it and create a jar from it. But not able to push jar to other repository. So, is there any way I can do it?

```groovy
node('docker_slave'){
   sh("git config --global user.email '******'")
   sh("git config --global user.name '*****'")
    stage('build'){
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
    branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
    extensions: [],
    submoduleCfg: [],
    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                 credentialsId: 'github', 
                 url: 'https://github.com/******/app.git']
                ]])
    sh("mvn clean package")
    sh("git add ./target/*.jar")
    sh("git commit -m 'testing apis'")
    }
    stage('push_git'){
      withCredentials([
              [$class: 'UsernamePasswordMultiBinding', 
              credentialsId: 'githubtest', 
              usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME',
              passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD']]) {
      sh("git push https://'**':'**'@github.com/**/app_release.git")
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is the size of jar file generated?

Comment: Jar size will be around 35-40mb @slashpai

Comment: I believe that size too huge for github. Normally max size for github would be like ~25MB